# I can't track page on analytics

Tags: google-analytics, forms

I have a form on a page that I have received 78 responses from. When I try to find and track this page to see how many people didn't submit the form, I can't find the page in analytics anywhere.

Comment: What are you doing to track the form: pageview, event, button click, etc?

Comment: I used Google's url builder tool to create a url that I used in my emails. Google analytics doesn't have any information on that page that I know at least 78 visited and completed the form.

Comment: So through the URL builder, you would be able to create custom campaigns for your email links and track how many people clicked that specific link from that specific email. This information can be found in Acquisition > Campaign. But it wouldn't show you how many people completed or didn't complete the form. You would need to use another form of tracking for that.

Comment: Thanks, I used Form Tools to manage the form. I found the campaign part and it says 25 sessions. I didn't put that much stock in that number because I know 78 people submitted the form. I thought the form page would show up in analytics, so I could just subtract submitted forms value from the total page views to get my conversion rate.

Comment: OK, I see. What you could (should?) do is to use a URL goal for the form completions. This would allow you to see how many people attempted , completed, or just gave up on the form.

Answer (score 1):

If a page isn't being tracked, you can use the [web tracking code setup help document](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008083?hl=en) to figure out what is wrong.  It suggests the following steps to debug the problem:

1. Check your Real-Time reports
2. Check the Tracking Status in your property
3. Install and use the Google Analytics Debugger extension
4. Use your browser's View Page Source feature to find the tracking code